# Create PNG icons from SVG with overlay text using imagemagick

Tags: svg, imagemagick

I'm trying to use `imagemagick` to generate PNG images from an SVG for use in a PWA. I'm having trouble working out which image is used when by the PWA. To debug this I'd like to annotate each generated PNG image with an index so I can tell which image the PWA uses in several different scenarios.

Below is an example of the command I'm using to create a 128x128 maskable PNG (10% margin) with white background from a source SVG.

```
convert -background "#ffffff" -density 1000 input.svg -gravity center -resize 128x128 -resize 80% -extent 128x128 icon-128x128.png
```

I would like to overlay an annotation (just a number, perhaps rendered in a black rectangle), something like this mockup:

[image]

How could I annotate the image such that the text fills about half the image regardless of the target resolution?

Comment: Based on the response from @fmw42, I modified my command to:

`magick -background "#ffffff" -density 1000 input.svg -gravity center -resize 128x128 -resize 80% -extent 128x128 -set option:dims "%[fx:w*0.8]x%[fx:h*0.8]" \( -size "%[dims]" -background "#000000aa" -fill white -gravity center label:"1" \) -gravity center -compose over -composite icon-128x128.png`

This gives me exactly what I was looking for. _Note_: You need to call `magick` intead of `convert`, which caught me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in one command line in ImageMagick 7 as follows. Assume the lena image is the result of your command. So I add the following just before the output:

[image]

Unix Syntax:

```
magick lena.png \
-set option:dims "%[fx:w/2]x%[fx:h/2]" \
\( -size "%[dims]" -background none -fill white -gravity center label:"1" \) \
-gravity center -compose over -composite \
result.png
```

[image]

If on Windows, change the line ending \ to ^ and remove the \ before the parentheses.

If on ImageMagick 6, you can do this by creating a large image of the numeral and then using -distort SRT to scale to the half size you want.

```
convert lena.png -set option:scale "%[fx:0.5*h/1000]" \
\( -size 1000x1000 -background none -fill white -gravity center label:"1" \
-distort SRT "%[scale] 0" \) \
-gravity center -compose over -composite \
result.png
```

[image]